# Inserting Multiple Data rows with a Loop in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, loops

Hi I am working on a project, and i am with days stuck in this little problem...

I have two tables, **"Bosses"** and **"Events"**. One Event can have one or more Bosses.

So what i want is inserting a new Event, and insert all the bosses that i choose. Actually is only inserting the last that i am selecting.

The Database
[image: The Database]

```
<?php

include "../paginas/conexion.php";

$nombr_reg = $_POST['nombr_reg'];
$descr_reg = $_POST['descr_reg'];
$fecre_reg = $_POST['fecre_reg'];
$statu_reg = 1;
$ident_ref = 1;

$sqlInsert = "
        INSERT INTO tab_reg(nombr_reg,descr_reg,fecre_reg,statu_reg) 
        VALUES ('$nombr_reg', '$descr_reg', '$fecre_reg', '$statu_reg')";       

    mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlInsert);

    $lastInsertId = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);

    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($_POST['ident_jef']); $i++) {
        $jefes = array($_POST['ident_jef']);
        $sqlInsertItem = "
        INSERT INTO det_reg(ident_reg, ident_jef) 
        VALUES ('$lastInsertId', '$jefes[$i]')";            
        mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlInsertItem);
    }      

  print_r($sqlInsert);
  print_r($sqlInsertItem);
  print_r($jefes);

  //header('location: ../paginas/registro_registro_exito.php');

  ?>
```

What the Form looks like
[image: What the Form looks like]

And this is what te `print_r();`'s are showing:

```
INSERT INTO tab_reg(nombr_reg,descr_reg,fecre_reg,statu_reg) VALUES ('PRUEBA 123', 'PRUEBA 123', '2019-12-25', '1') INSERT INTO det_reg(ident_reg, ident_jef) VALUES ('122', '')Array ( [0] => 3 )
```

I know that the problem is with the for, or maybe i have to use a foreach, but i am really confused.

Thanks to everyone and Happy New Year!

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem in assign array to a new array in `for` loop. Try this:

```
 ...
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, "INSERT INTO det_reg(ident_reg, ident_jef) 
         VALUES (?, ?)");
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['ident_jef']); $i++) { //you have an array here
         $jefes = $_POST['ident_jef'];             
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $lastInsertId, $jefes[$i]);            
         mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
```

Here is the test example:

```
$array=[
    "Title 1",
    "Title 2",
    "Title 3"
];
$desc = "Description";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO table1(title, description) VALUES (?, ?)");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) { //you have an array here
     $jefes = $array;
     var_dump("Test" . $i);
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $jefes[$i], $desc);    
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Mysql Table 1:

[image]

Comment: There must be an error, i am getting "this page is not working - HTTP Error 500.

Comment: Try it again, I edited answer, your table accept integers, I accidentally put there doubles.

Comment: I look at it, but there is nothing relevant

Comment: I moved `stmt` out from `loop`, try now. I will try on my server right now.

Comment: Same problem, yet

Comment: I get this: "string(5) "Test0" string(5) "Test1" string(5) "Test2"". But is not inserting in the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205167/discussion-between-serghei-leonenco-and-carlos-agustin-guanipa-alvarez).

Comment: Does you fix your issue?

Comment: Not yet... it's driving me crazy